# Is there a way to temporarily change the terminal colour?

Tags: linux, bash, colors, gnome-terminal, background-process

I use the `gnome-terminal` and most of my editors with a white on black theme as I find its easier on the eyes. One of my labs requires screenshots of the terminal (with the process) to be submitted along with program code.

So, is there a way to temporarily change the terminal to a black on white colour scheme, preferably from within the terminal itself ?

If not, is there a way to launch a child terminal with the inverted colour scheme, without affecting the parent terminal ?

Comment: Why don't you simply invert the colors of the screen shot? It should be a one-liner with ImageMagick or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use gconftool-2 - GNOME configuration tool. First, you can list all your gnome profiles with:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list
[Default,Profile0]
```

Now you can print values for selected profile:

```
$ gconftool-2 -a "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default"
```

Store value of foreground and background color:

```
$ gconftool-2 --get "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color"
#000000000000
$ gconftool-2 --get "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color"
#EEEEEEEEECEC
```

Now you can turn off using theme colours:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors" --type bool false
```

And set your own colours:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#EEEEEEEEECEC"
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "#000000000000"
```

Comment: Thanks. You could have said to put the last two commands in the same line. I had a white on white terminal for a few moments!